# Event reverses tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events

A dizzying question for experts. When I click on my `<span>` in the my `ul` it's font-style becomes unset, i.e. reset. How do I save my charming font-styles against evil 'events'?

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul')

ul.addEventListener('click', function (evn) {
  let li = evn.target.closest('li');
  if (evn.target !== this) li.textContent += '!'
})
```

```css
.i {
    font-style: italic;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>hello text bye</li>
    <li>hello text bye</li>
    <li>hello <span class="i">text</span> bye</li>
</ul>
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing

```
li.textContent += '!'
```

is like doing

```
const origText = li.textContent;
li.textContent = origText + '!'
```

And assigning to the `.textContent` of an element always inserts text only, in the form of a text node - no elements will ever be produced. If the parent originally had an element child, the element will be replaced with only its text.

For the same reason, the button disappears below:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.parentElement.textContent += '';
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button>click</button>
</div>
```

Use `.insertAdjacentText` instead of `.textContent +=`.

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul')

ul.addEventListener('click', function (evn) {
  let li = evn.target.closest('li');
  if (evn.target !== this) li.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', '!');
})
```

```css
.i {
    font-style: italic;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>hello text bye</li>
    <li>hello text bye</li>
    <li>hello <span class="i">text</span> bye</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're modifying the `.textContent` itself, all inner html that's not text is stripped away. You can add a new text node to make this work. Note that this can clog up html, so if the last node is already a text node, just add to it.

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul')

ul.addEventListener('click', function (evn) {
  let li = evn.target.closest('li');
  if (evn.target !== this) {
    const lastNode = [...li.childNodes].at(-1);
    if (lastNode.nodeType === 3) lastNode.textContent += "!";
    else li.append("!");
  }
})
```

```css
.i {
    font-style: italic;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>hello text bye</li>
    <li>hello text bye</li>
    <li>hello <span class="i">text</span> bye</li>
</ul>
```